# Capture Paste Event in NSTextfield

Tags: cocoa, swift3, appkit

I have a application, where I have to capture the paste event for the NSTextField.
Two scenario is required:
If text is typed, call goes to controlTextDidChange
If paste action is done in text field, again this controlTextDidChange delegate is called.
I need to differentiate between Paste action and type action NSTextField. It is required as I need to call separate function.

Please suggest, how to capture Paste Action for the NSTextField.

Thanks in Advance.
Raghunath

Comment: post what code you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect paste on NSTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881770/detect-paste-on-nstextfield)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

You can intercept the paste command by using a custom field editor and overriding `paste`. Documentation:[Text Fields, Text Views, and the Field Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextFieldsAndViews/TextFieldsAndViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH8-BBCFEBHA) and [Using a Custom Field Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH3-SW35).

This answer might be helpful: [NSTextField: exposing its Copy and Paste methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38863274/4244136). You don't have to use a subclass of `NSTextFieldCell`, you can also use the method `windowWillReturnFieldEditor` of `NSWindowDelegate`.